# Sending emails using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to send some emails using nodemailer via this snippet of code putted into my server.js

server.js

```
var smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "abc@gmail.com",
        pass: "pass"
    }
});

var mail = {
    from: "Contact <abc@gmail.com>",
    to: "abc@gmail.com",
    Subject: "Test sujet",
    text: "test text",
    html: "<b>Test text</b>"
}

smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(err, res){
    console.log(err, "Message sent: ");
    smtpTransport.close();
})
```

But, when I node that server.js I get this error message:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' } 'Message sent: '
```

**EDIT :** Refering [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654736/nodemailer-econnrefused), I've also tried to check my ssl connection `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465` (it's working).

How do I please to fix it ?

Comment: `Subject` vs `subject` maybe? I also used service `Gmail`.

Comment: @chovy, it still the same :/

Comment: looks same for my project, but i havent' ran this code in 2 years.

Comment: @chovy, I'm doing this locally using the node command on my server.js

Comment: What version of nodemailer are you using? http://www.andrisreinman.com/nodemailer-v1-0/#migrationguide

Answer (score -5, accepted):

you can remove "SMTP" options.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error and followed the link that nfreeze sent in the comment. For your code, it would look something like this. I hope this helps!

```
  var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
  var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: { user: 'abc@gmail.com',
        pass: 'pass' }
  }));

  transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'Contact <abc@gmail.com>',
    to: "abc@gmail.com",
    subject: 'Test sujet',
    text: "test text",
    html: "<b>Test text</b>"
  }, function (error, response) {
    //Email not sent
    if (error) {
      res.end("Email send Falied");
    }
    //email send sucessfully
    else {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
```

Comment: THIS SHOULD BE THE ACCEPTED ANSWER