# Nodemailer for GMX

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I wrote my code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654736/nodemailer-econnrefused) article.

Code:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'mail.gmx.com',
auth: {
    user: '...@gmx.de',
    pass: '...'
}
```

});

"Nodemailer is not defined" or "ECONNREFUSED".

The connection informations I got from [Link1](https://hilfe.gmx.net/mailprogramme/pop3.html) and [Link2](http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-gmx).

Any experiences with GMX ?

Answer (score 2):

`mail.gmx.com` is not a 'common service' - it's a host. You'll need to set it up like this using `host`, `port`, etc.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'mail.gmx.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'username',
        pass: 'password'
    }
}));
```

Comment: Then you'll need to use the documentation (https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport#usage) to set it up properly.

Comment: Different Eror.For sending emails it uses "Server: mail.gmx.net, Port: 587,Encryption: STARTTLS", i tried it with port 25 also, now I get "{ [Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain] code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN' }" seems to be a encryption problem ?. https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fhilfe.gmx.net%2Fmailprogramme%2Fpop3.html&edit-text=

Comment: Now I get the following error: "{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }" , I think I need to set it explicity to Encryption: STARTTLS ?! Or set to "ignoreTLS: true,", but now I get "{ [Error: Invalid login]
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-Authentication credentials invalid\n535 Insufficient security or privacy level.',
  responseCode: 535 }" But my user credentials work, I tried it manually ...

Answer (score 2):

This nodemailer settings are working for testing purpose mail.
After that we can make secure or SSL based

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'mail.gmx.com',
  port: 587,
  tls: {
    ciphers:'SSLv3',
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  },
  debug:true,
    auth: {
    user: '...@gmx.de',
    pass: '...'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
this works out for me:

```
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mail.gmx.com',
    port: 587,
    tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3',
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    debug:true,
        auth: {
        user: '...@gmx.de',
        pass: '...'
    }
});
```

I found the solution based on [this article](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/issues/310), but "rejectUnauthorized: false" seems not to be a good solution...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with web.de-Mail. You have to check the WWW-Site your emails an there is a hint from the provider. **You have to activate smtp/pop3! there. For security reasons**.

```
 let transporter = createTransport({
                host: 'smtp.web.de',
                port: 587,
                tls:{
                    ciphers : 'SSLv3',
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                },
                auth:{
                        user: '.....@web.de',
                        pass: '......'
                }
            });
```