# How to add email attachment to strapi provider email nodemailer

Tags: email-attachments, nodemailer, strapi

I'm trying to send a confirmation email with attachments with strapi-provider-email-nodemailer. The plugin [clearly supports attachments](https://github.com/yutikom/strapi-provider-email-nodemailer/blob/master/lib/index.js), but I don't know where in the strapi backend am I suppose to add these attachments. Does anyone know how to add attachments to an email sent via strapi-nodemailer?

Answer (score 2):

In the end the solution was quite complicated. Probably there is an easier, undocumented way to do this with Strapi, but I don't know it.

In the end, I had to create an whole new API according to the quick start guide, so create a new content type 'Register' and create my own custom controller and service that uses the `strapi.plugins['email']` and `strapi.plugins[users-permissions]`.

Strapi automatically generates the models and documentations and routes for you, but you gotta edit the controllers and services.

register/config/routes.json

```
{
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/registers",
      "handler": "Register.create",
      "config": {
        "policies": [],
        "description": "Register a user"
      }
    },
```

register/controllers/Register.js

```
module.exports = {
  create: async ctx => {
    try {
      let addUser = await strapi.services.register.registerUser(
        ctx.request.body
      );
      let sendEmail = await strapi.services.register.sendEmail(
        ctx.request.body
      );
      ctx.send({
        user: addUser,
        email: sendEmail
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
};
```

register/services/Register.js (make sure there is an image in the public folder)

```
'use strict';
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  registerUser: async data => {
    let result = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.add({
      username: data.username,
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password
    });
    return result;
  },
  sendEmail: async data => {
    console.log(__dirname);
    let result = await strapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send({
      to: data.email,
      from: 'whatever@whatever.com',
      replyTo: 'whatever@whatever.com',
      subject: 'Use strapi email provider successfully',
      text: 'Hello world foo!',
      html: 'Embedded image: <img src="cid:my_logo@nodemailer.com"/>',
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: 'surmile_logo.PNG',
          path: path.join(
            __dirname + '/../../../public/uploads/my_logo.png'
          ),
          cid: 'my_logo@nodemailer.com'
        }
      ]
    });
    return result;
  }
};
```

Then `strapi build` and `strapi start`
Make a POST to http://localhost:1337/registers
with json body

```
{
  "username": "sausage",
  "email": "blah@gmail.com",
  "password": "123456"
}
```

Make sure that you grant permissions for everyone to access the route in the admin panel
[image]

Make sure [your client is properly configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654736/nodemailer-econnrefused/44133190#44133190)