# Nodemailer not working with local smtp server

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have setup local smtp server in my linux machine.
The following command works and successfully received mail from test@<machine-name>.

```
echo “THIS IS A TEST EMAIL” | mail -s "This is subject" xxxx@gmail.com
```

Whereas I need to send mail using `nodemailer` which I have configured as below,

```
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host:"smtp.<ourserver>.com",
        secure:false
    });
    const info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'test@<machine-name>', // sender address
        to: 'xxxx@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        subject: "Hello", // Subject line
        html: "<i>Hello world</i>" // html body
    });
```

But I am getting the following error,

[image]

Any idea why I am facing this issue?

I have seen similar questions posted in quora but none of them solved my problem.

With [emailjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs), it works with the following config,

```
  const { SMTPClient } = require('emailjs');
  const client = new SMTPClient({
       host: 'smtp.<ourserver>.com',
       ssl: false,
       tls: false
  });
  client.send(
    {
       text: 'Hello',
       from: 'test@<machine-name>',
       to: 'xxx@gmail.com',
       subject: 'Hello',
    },
    (err, message) => {
         //
    }
 );
```

How can I make it work using `nodemailer`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a firewall problem. Please have a look there first - maybe you can disable it for testing purposes?

The problem has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654736/nodemailer-econnrefused).

Comment: But if it is firewall problem then it should not work with emailjs as well right?

Comment: Not necessarily but I don't know how emailjs works right now.

Comment: Maybe set the port manually to 25 because by default it is set to 587 if you set secure:false.

Comment: I have tried setting it to 25 as well but in vain. Thanks anyways! will check it.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor Wedlich it is working in port 25. I didn't know how I missed it.