# Node mailer gives the rest mail ECONNREFUSED error in server after sending 6 successfull mail always

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am facing a problem related node mailing service. I am trying to send mail by node mailer in windows server. Out 15 mail or 12 mail it always send first 6 mail success fully.For the rest mail i am getting connection refused error.
Node version: 10.16.0
Node mailer version:^4.4.2

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 198.57.247.139:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '198.57.247.139',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

I dont understand what is the problem here. It is not happening in my local environment.
If you can give me an idea it will be very help full.
Thank you

Comment: Can you check the function sending the emails. I think it might be causing the server crash and when it tries to restart but fails due to process being in running state.

Comment: @SunnyParekh checking it now. thanks for commenting.

Comment: @SunnyParekh I am using recusrive fucntion to send all the mail one by one. I havent find anything in the function that seems to crash the server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654736/nodemailer-econnrefused Check this if it helps

Comment: checking . thanks for the link. checking it.